# How to track the file that loads an specific line from a rendered HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a website in Wordpress and recently we discovered that it was infected by several malware scripts that insert scripts using the common base64 and eval functions like this:

[image]

We were able to solve most of the infected files but there are still some scripts being injected into the index.html, like these:

[image]

All these scripts marked in red make a requests to sites that immediately trigger my computer antivirus.

**So question here is, how can I track which file loads these lines? How can I know which file prints them?** I can't just search for the string since the code is encrypted like on the first image...

Comment: I expect these are being appended to the DOM via javascript

Comment: change the permissions of your PHP files to read-only on the server.

Comment: @pcnate it may be, how can I know? If it is loaded as you say, what would that mean? I'm still unable to know which file loads it.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I don't think that would work but I may be wrong... I think that PHP generates a "temporary" file that is then sent to the user as a HTML source code. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong? Would changing the file permission help?

Comment: Try changing theme in WordPress or keep disabling any plugins on-by-one and check script loads (take a backup of data and current theme first)

Answer (score 1):

The truth is, it's probably going to be more than one file, and/or it's going to be something hidden deep in a plugin/upload folder.

This is going to be a bit time-consuming, but these are generally the steps I follow when fixing a hacked site to narrow things down and make sure I got all the crap out:

1) Before you do anything else, make sure you have a backup of both the files and db. That way, if you accidentally delete something, it's easy to restore.

2) Delete any unused themes or plugins, and make sure all existing plugins are up-to-date.

3) Update WordPress to the current version. Seriously. Keeping up-to-date is important. If you're more than two major releases behind, you'll want to update incrementally. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions)

4) After you've updated, connect via FTP and look for files older than when you updated.  Look for extra files that shouldn't be there--this can be tricky, because hacked files are usually named things like wp-shortcode-s.php. I usually have a copy of WP core files open in a window beside my FTP client as a reference.

5) Check the first few lines of code on php and js files in your plugins folder for malicious code.  Again, you might want to have a freshly downloaded copy of the plugin to compare files to.

6) Check the uploads folder and subfolders for malicious files.

I also keep checking my hacked site here to see how I'm doing:

http://isithacked.com/

And when you're finished, you might want to read up on how to harden WP to make it more difficult to hack.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the source of the malware, it's hard to give you a precise hint. There are a few more in-depth walk-through about the topic you can find on Google, here are some good examples which could help:

https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/

https://blog.sucuri.net/2011/02/cleaning-up-an-infected-web-site-part-i-wordpress-and-the-pharma-hack.html

Also if you are on a shared host, potentially the issue could be coming from an other compromised user. Hopefully you have a clean version of the site so that potentially moving to an other host (and upgrading) is an option.